# PHP regex: How to extract url and filter "\" from specific string

Tags: php, regex, url, extract

I'm a newbie with programming; now, I have some problems with PHP programing.

I want to extract the URL from the following `string`：

```
"success":true,"load":"http:\/\/8.88.88.8\/list\/si3diwoe\/123","Live":true
```

The desired `string` is

```
http://8.88.88.8/list/si3diwoe/123
```

Can anyone tell me how this work in code?
Thank you very much!

Comment: That looks like part of a JSON string to me. Don't use regular expressions to replace a proper parser. PHP comes with a nice JSON implementation, so if you can, use `json_decode()` and then access the property you need directly.

Comment: it's missing { and } brackets to be a JSON, but besides that, you are right.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm learning PHP programing, don't konw JSON, If you can tell de PHP code ,I will the appreciate. I can use command  preg_match with regex (?<=load":").*?(?=","Live) to extract string : http:\/\/8.88.88.8\/list\/si3diwoe\/123, but don't know how to filter /.

Comment: <?php
$str='"success":true,"load":"http:\/\/8.88.88.8\/list\/si3diwoe\/123","Live":true';
$pattern='((?<=load":").*?(?=","Live))';
preg_match($pattern,$str,$match);
$url = preg_replace('(\\)','', $match);
var_dump($url);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '"success":true,"load":"http:\/\/8.88.88.8\/list\/si3diwoe\/123","Live":true';

// The JSON way
$array = json_decode('{' . $string . '}'); // Wrap in {} to make object
$url   = $array->load;
echo "Using JSON : $url", PHP_EOL;

// The RegEx way
preg_match('/load":"(.*?)"/', $string, $matches);
$url = stripslashes($matches[1]);
echo "Using RegEx: $url", PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Using JSON : http://8.88.88.8/list/si3diwoe/123
Using RegEx: http://8.88.88.8/list/si3diwoe/123
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, it is birfe and work fine. very help full for me, but I think there may be a way to use one regex to mach the correct url, I will find out that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a json string, you can use json_decode to assign it to a variable, say $arr, then stripslashes($arr['load']);

if it's not, you can use explode("," , $string),  and assign it to a variable, say $arr again. Run explode again (explode(":", $arr[1])) and assigned it to another variable, say $ar, then do stripslashes on $ar['1'];

Comment: thank for your replay, my main purpose is want to know whether regex can do such thing ,I try the code '
$str='"success":true,"load":"http:\/\/8.88.88.8\/list\/si3diwoe\/123","Live":true';
$pattern='((?<=load":").*?(?=","Live))';
preg_match($pattern,$str,$match);
$url = preg_replace('\\','', $match);
var_dump($url);
' it  not work, I know split the string and recombine it will work, I want to try use less code to do this. but thanks you answer.